# FTP error 227 and error 500

Tags: c#-4.0, ftp

Thanks in advance for any help that may be forthcoming.

I am trying to get an FTP download to work in c#.

I download the following code.

```
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

     FtpWebRequest FTP;

        try
        {

            FileStream SR = new FileStream("C:\\dave" + "file1.xml", FileMode.Create);



            FTP = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(new Uri("ftp://xxx.xxx.xxx" + "file1.xml"));

            FTP.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("userid", "password");

            FTP.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;


            FTP.EnableSsl = false;                
            FTP.UseBinary = true;
            FTP.UsePassive = true;

            FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)FTP.GetResponse();
            Stream ftpStream = response.GetResponseStream();

            long cl = response.ContentLength;

        int bufferSize = 2048;
        int readCount;

        byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
        readCount = ftpStream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
        while (readCount > 0)
        {
            SR.Write(buffer, 0, readCount);
            readCount = ftpStream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
        }
        ftpStream.Close();
        SR.Close();
        response.Close();
        MessageBox.Show("File Downloaded!");

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error");
        }   
    }
```

and updated it to include the valid ftpsite, userid and passwords.

On execution if get a 227 error when passive is set to true, however when I change passive to false I get 500 error.

The FTPsite is external to our company, but using FileZilla I can download the files I require.

Can anyone give me any possible answers or ways to resolve my problem or even point me in the right direction

Thanks

Dave